# Can't update Android Studio to 2.1.1, validation fails with missing bouncy-castle

Tags: android-studio-2.1

There is an Emergency security patch to patch vulnerabilities found in IntelliJ platform. [Here is a news article about it](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/05/11/emergency-patch-issued-for-android-studio-and-intellij-based-ides-to-close-up-two-serious-security-vulnerabilities/)

However when hitting patch the update button, Android Studio downloads the patch, shuts off Android Studio, enters the updater with elevated privilages (I am using Windows 10), starts validating my install, and FAILS THE VALIDATION with this message:

```
gradle/m2repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/    Validate    Absent  NONE
gradle/m2repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.48/   Validate    Absent  NONE
gradle/m2repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.48/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.48.pom    Validate    Absent  NONE
gradle/m2repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.48/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.48.jar    Validate    Absent  NONE
gradle/m2repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.48/NOTICE Validate    Absent  NONE
gradle/m2repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.48/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.48-sources.jar    Validate    Absent  NONE
gradle/m2repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/    Validate    Absent  NONE
gradle/m2repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.48/   Validate    Absent  NONE
gradle/m2repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.48/bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.pom    Validate    Absent  NONE
gradle/m2repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.48/bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar    Validate    Absent  NONE
gradle/m2repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.48/NOTICE Validate    Absent  NONE
gradle/m2repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.48/bcprov-jdk15on-1.48-sources.jar    Validate    Absent  NONE
```

And the only option it provides is to cancel the update. How do I successfully install the patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this is a bad answer but the best I could come up with.
Basically, I downloaded the [full installer package](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-1-1), opened it with 7zip, browsed to gradle/m2repository/org, copied the bouncycastle folder, and pasted in [Android Studio Install Directory]/gradle/m2repository/org.

Then the patch passed validation and successfully updated to 2.1.1

Comment: thanks it worked, maybe not the better solution but it does the trick :)